# Having similar Problems in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, attributes

**Here is my code , and i get frequently attribute error , i dont know where is the fault :**

```
from tkinter import*
class Student:
    def __init__(self,root):
    
       self.root=root
       self.root.title("Customer Management System")
       self.root.geometry("1350x780+0+0")

       title=Label(self,root,text="SUNBIRD TAILORS",font=("times new 
       roman",40,"bold"),bg="blue",fg="white")
       title.pack(side=TOP)
   
 root=Tk()
 ob = Student(root)
 root.mainloop()
```

And the error is like :
self.tk = master.tk
Attribute Error: 'Student' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: Get rid of `self` in your `Label` arguments. It might not fix your current problem, but it will fix the next problem you will have. ... actually it probably will fix your current problem. `self` is `Student` and `Student` is not a `widget` but you are trying to use it as a master. Really, the way you are trying to connect this stuff together is poor.

Comment: Typo error, `Label(self,root,...)` should be `Label(self.root,...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `self` as the first argument to `Label`. That argument must be a widget, but `Student` isn't a widget. Just remove `self`:

```
title=Label(root,text="SUNBIRD TAILORS",font=("times new roman",40,"bold"),bg="blue",fg="white")
```